# Java Uploaded file is not the same

Tags: java, file, file-upload, upload

my problem is the following, I'm trying to upload a file to my server via servlet but the uploaded file is not the same, it has differences compared to the original one.

For example, If I upload TXT file for example

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p     %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\filesLog\\log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p         %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The upload file has a new line with

`...`
`NULNULNULNULNULNUL`

(Opened with Notepad++).

If the file is a .exe, the uploaded file doesn't work.

My code is the following

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        System.out.println("ES UN REQUEST MULTIPART " + isMultipart);
        // Set factory constraints
        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        // Set overall request size constraint
        // MAX REQUEST SIZE
        // Parse the request
        // List / FileItem / items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            // FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            FileItemStream itemS = (FileItemStream) iter.next();

            if (itemS.isFormField() == false) {
                // Process a file upload
                String fileName = itemS.getName();
                System.out.println("FILE NAME " + fileName);
                // Process a file upload
                File uploadedFile = new File("C:\\FilesUpload\\" + UUID.randomUUID());
                // InputStream uploadedStream = item.getInputStream();

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile);
                BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(itemS.openStream());
                byte buf[] = new byte[2048];
                Long contador = 0L;
                while ((bin.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    bout.write(buf);
                    contador = contador + 1L;
                }
                bout.close();
                bin.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
 while ((bin.read(buf)) != -1) {
        bout.write(buf);
        contador = contador + 1L;
    }
```

You are not checking how many bytes have been read. The last buffer read, if the length of the file is not *exactly* divisible by 2048, will only be read partially. In that case, `bin.read(buf)` will return the number of bytes read, and you should only use that number when you write `buf`, otherwise you'll write all the 2048 bytes in `buf`, including values from your previous reads or zeros if this is the first read.

So it should be something like this:

```
 int numBytesRead;
 while ((numBytesRead = bin.read(buf)) != -1) {
        bout.write(buf,0,numBytesRead);
        contador = contador + 1L;
 }
```

This will make it write exactly what it read and no more.

By the way, if you are using Java 7 and above, then instead of doing all this, you can use `Files.copy` to copy the whole stream directly to your file.

```
Files.copy(itemS.openStream(),
           Paths.get("C:\\FilesUpload\\" + UUID.randomUUID()),
           StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the

```
bout.write(buf)
```

I you will write the whole buffer even if parts of it is null.

Note your `buf` is `2048` bytes..

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the value returned from `bin.read(buf)`, which indicates the number of bytes read.  There is no guarantee that the read operation filled up your buffer.  Therefore, many of your calls to `bout.write(buf)` are writing garbage data.

Here is a much simpler way (and therefore less prone to bugs) to save an InputStream to a file:

```
Files.copy(bin, uploadedFile.toPath());
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).